# OpenWRT + TP-Link wr741-nd потеря lan

Tags: openwrt

Всем доброго времени суток, после установки openwrt на данный роутер после перезагрузки роутера, стало пропадать lan соединение причем wifi работает отлично, запустив ping на шлюз, увидел что после перезагрузки роутера принятых пакетов коло 15, далее привышен интервал и связь возможно востановить только повторным ребутом и опять на 5-10 сек. Пробовал заного прошить через Telnet симптомы остались прежними. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема ? как её решить и решаема ли она ?

> root@OpenWrt:~# dmesg [    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.23
>
> (buildbot@builder1) (gcc version 4.8.3 (OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04
>    r47269) ) #1 Sun Jan 31 18:39:35 CET 2016
>
> [    0.000000] MyLoader:sysp=662b810a, boardp=2755c6fe, parts=483f1687
>   [    0.000000]
>
> bootconsole [early0] enabled [    0.000000] CPU0 revision is: 00019374
>    (MIPS 24Kc) [    0.000000]
>
> SoC: Atheros AR9330 rev 1 [    0.000000]
>
> Determined physical RAM map:
>
> [    0.000000]  memory: 02000000 @ 00000000 (usable)
>
> [    0.000000] Initrd not found or empty - disabling initrd
>
> [    0.000000] Zone ranges:
>
> [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00000000-0x01ffffff]
>
> [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
>
> [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
>
> [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000-0x01ffffff]
>
> [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x00000000-0x01ffffff]
>
> [    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 8192
>
> [0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 803762b0, node_mem_map
>   81000000
>
> [0.000000]   Normal zone: 64 pages used for memmap
>
> [0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
>
> [0.000000]   Normal zone: 8192 pages, LIFO batch:0
>
> [0.000000] Primary instruction cache 64kB, VIPT, 4-way, linesize 32
>   bytes.
>
> [0.000000] Primary data cache 32kB, 4-way, VIPT, cache aliases,
>   linesize 32 bytes
>
> [0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
>
> [0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
>
> [0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on. 
>   Total pages: 8128
>
> [0.000000] Kernel command line:  board=TL-WR741ND-v4 
>   console=ttyATH0,115200 rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2 noinitrd
>
> [0.000000] PID hash table entries: 128 (order: -3, 512 bytes)
>
> [0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384
>   bytes)
>
> [0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
>
> [0.000000] Writing ErrCtl register=00000000
>
> [0.000000] Readback ErrCtl register=00000000
>
> [0.000000] Memory: 28324K/32768K available (2586K kernel code, 128K
>   rwdata, 540K rodata, 256K init, 193K bss, 4444K reserved)
>
> [0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
>
> [0.000000] NR_IRQS:51
>
> [0.000000] Clocks: CPU:400.000MHz, DDR:400.000MHz, AHB:200.000MHz,
>   Ref:25.000MHz
>
> [0.000000] Calibrating delay loop... 265.42 BogoMIPS (lpj=1327104)
>
> [0.080000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
>
> [0.080000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
>
> [0.090000] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096
>   bytes)
>
> [0.100000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
>
> [0.100000] MIPS: machine is TP-LINK TL-WR741ND v4
>
> [0.570000] Switched to clocksource MIPS
>
> [0.570000] NET: Registered protocol family 2
>
> [0.580000] TCP established hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096
>   bytes)
>
> [0.580000] TCP bind hash table entries:1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
>
> [0.580000] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1024 bind 1024)
>
> [0.590000] TCP: reno registered
>
> [0.590000] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
>
> [0.600000] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
>
> [0.610000] NET: Registered protocol family 1
>
> [0.610000] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 32
>
> [0.610000] futex hash table entries: 256 (order:-1, 3072 bytes)
>
> [0.630000] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
>
> [0.630000] jffs2: version 2.2 (NAND) (SUMMARY)(LZMA) (RTIME)
>   (CMODE_PRIORITY) (c) 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
>
> [0.640000] msgmni has been set to 55
>
> [0.640000] io scheduler noop registered
>
> [0.650000] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
>
> [0.650000] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 16 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
>
> [0.660000] ar933x-uart: ttyATH0 at MMIO 0x18020000 (irq = 11,
>   base_baud = 1562500) is a AR933X UART
>
> [0.670000] console [ttyATH0] enabled
>
> [0.680000] bootconsole [early0] disabled
>
> [0.690000] m25p80 spi0.0: found s25sl032p, expected m25p80
>
> [0.690000] m25p80 spi0.0: s25sl032p (4096 Kbytes)
>
> [0.700000] 5 tp-link partitions found on MTD device spi0.0
>
> [0.700000] Creating 5 MTD partitions on "spi0.0":
>
> [0.710000] 0x000000000000-0x000000020000 : "u-boot"
>
> [0.710000] 0x000000020000-0x00000013f608 : "kernel"
>
> [0.720000] 0x00000013f608-0x0000003f0000 : "rootfs"
>
> [0.720000] mtd: device 2(rootfs) set to be root filesystem
>
> [0.730000] 1 squashfs-split partitions found on MTD device rootfs
>
> [0.730000] 0x000000360000-0x0000003f0000 : "rootfs_data"
>
> [0.740000] 0x0000003f0000-0x000000400000 : "art"
>
> [0.740000] 0x000000020000-0x0000003f0000 : "firmware"
>
> [0.780000] libphy: ag71xx_mdio: probed
>
> [1.380000] ag71xx-mdio.1: Found an AR7240/AR9330 built-in switch
>
> [1.410000] eth0: Atheros AG71xx at 0xba000000, irq 5, mode:GMII
>
> [2.000000] ag71xx ag71xx.0: connected to PHY at ag71xx-mdio.1:04
>   [uid=004dd041, driver=Generic PHY]
>
> [2.010000] eth1: Atheros AG71xx at 0xb9000000, irq 4, mode:MII
>
> [2.010000] TCP: cubic registered
>
> [2.010000] NET: Registered protocol family 17
>
> [2.020000] bridge: automatic filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables has been
>   deprecated. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
>
> [2.030000] Bridge firewalling registered
>
> [2.040000] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
>
> [2.050000] VFS: Mounted root (squashfs filesystem) readonly on device
>   31:2.
>
> [2.060000] Freeing unused kernel memory: 256K (80390000 - 803d0000)
>
> [3.410000] init: Console is alive
>
> [3.410000] init: watchdog
>
> [5.490000] init: - preinit -
>
> [6.280000] random: procd urandom read with 9 bits of entropy available
>
> [8.350000] eth0: link up (1000Mbps/Full duplex)
>
> [9.680000] jffs2: notice: (345) jffs2_build_xattr_subsystem: complete
>   building xattr subsystem, 0 of xdatum (0 unchecked, 0 orphan) and 0 of
>   xref (0 dead, 0 orphan) found.
>
> [9.690000] mount_root: switching to jffs2 overlay
>
> [9.750000] eth0: link down
>
> [9.760000] procd: - early -
>
> [9.760000] procd: - watchdog -
>
> [10.650000] procd: - ubus -
>
> [11.660000] procd: - init -
>
> [12.610000] NET: Registered protocol family 10
>
> [12.620000] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
>
> [12.640000] Loading modules backported from Linux version
>   master-2015-03-09-0-g141f155
>
> [12.650000] Backport generated by backports.git
>   backports-20150129-0-gdd4a670
>
> [12.660000] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
>
> [12.680000] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (446 buckets, 1784 max)
>
> [12.730000] xt_time: kernel timezone is -0000
>
> [12.770000] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
>
> [12.770000] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
>
> [12.780000] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
>
> [12.780000] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth),
>   (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
>
> [12.790000] cfg80211:(2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A,
>   2000 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [12.800000] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000
>   KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [12.810000] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A,
>   2000 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [12.820000] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000
>   KHz AUTO),(N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A) [   12.830000] cfg80211:   (5250000
>   KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0
>   s)
>
> [12.830000] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz),
>   (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s) [   12.840000] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz -
>   5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [12.850000] cfg80211:(57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz),
>   (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [12.960000] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
>
> [12.960000] NET: Registered protocol family 24
>
> [13.030000] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x0
>
> [13.030000] ath: EEPROM indicates default country code should be used
>
> [13.030000] ath: doing EEPROM country regdmn map search
>
> [13.030000] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
>
> [13.030000] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
>
> [13.030000] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
>
> [13.040000] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm
>   'minstrel_ht'
>
> [13.040000] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9330 Rev:1 mem=0xb8100000, irq=2
>
> [13.050000] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
>
> [13.050000] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
>
> [13.060000] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
>
> [13.060000] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth),
>   (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
>
> [13.070000] cfg80211:(2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A,
>   3000 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [13.080000] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000
>   KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [13.090000] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000
>   KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0s)
>
> [13.100000] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000KHz), (N/A,
>   2300 mBm), (0 s)
>
> [13.110000] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A,
>   3000 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [13.120000] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz),
>   (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
>
> [23.670000] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
>
> [23.670000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-lan: link is not ready
>
> [23.700000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
>
> [25.620000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
>
> [25.630000] eth0: link up (1000Mbps/Full duplex)
>
> [   25.630000] br-lan: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
>
> [25.640000] br-lan: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
>
> [   25.660000] device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode
>
> [   25.690000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-lan: link becomes
>   ready
>
> [   25.700000] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
>
> [   25.700000] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
>
> [   25.710000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes
>   ready
>
> [   25.920000] eth1: link up (100Mbps/Full duplex)
>
> [   25.920000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
>
> [   27.640000] br-lan: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
>
> [  27.700000] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
>
> [   37.320000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   37.330000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   37.330000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   37.340000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   37.350000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   37.360000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   37.920000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   37.920000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   38.230000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   38.230000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   43.240000] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
>
> [   56.960000] net_ratelimit: 1 callbacks suppressed
>
> [   56.960000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   57.240000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   58.620000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   60.720000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   61.720000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   61.930000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   61.940000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   64.440000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   74.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   74.990000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   75.990000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   76.540000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   76.550000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   77.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   78.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   79.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   81.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   82.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   83.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   89.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   90.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   91.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   98.750000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   98.760000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [   98.800000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  105.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  106.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  107.000000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  158.940000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  159.940000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  160.940000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  164.420000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  165.600000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  165.710000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  165.930000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  165.940000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  170.020000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  174.060000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  175.280000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  217.100000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  218.100000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  219.100000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  312.810000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  420.970000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  423.130000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  425.470000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  426.640000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  429.900000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  430.520000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  430.540000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  524.520000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  524.960000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  525.520000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  526.520000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  526.720000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  526.720000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  526.740000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  526.750000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  533.470000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  534.470000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  535.470000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  536.520000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  537.520000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  538.520000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  539.570000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  540.570000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  541.570000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  542.620000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [ 543.620000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  544.620000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  545.670000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address
>
> [  546.670000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as
>   source address

Comment: как и всегда — см. логи. в данном случае — с помощью `$ dmesg` и [`$ logread`](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/log.essentials).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Все в одно сообщение не вместилось, ниже логи с logread. И еще самое интересно ip сетевая получает но на шлюз не пингуется. Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: непонятно, зачем вы это всё «вывалили». я предложил смотреть логи. вам самому смотреть. здесь, увы, не техподдержка.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо посмотрел, что я должен здесь увидеть ? Точнее где найти почему ip роутер присваивает а сам не пингуется ?  Человек не знающий куда именно копать и обращается за помощью, не так ли ? ну да ладно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

> root@OpenWrt:~# logread Tue Dec  6 14:45:35 2016 kern.warn kernel: [
>   1701.760000] br-lan: received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:45:36 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1703.180000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:45:36 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1703.370000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:45:38 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1705.260000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:45:40 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1706.740000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:45:43 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1709.860000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:46:37 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1763.740000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:02 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1848.810000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:21 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:21 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[1200]: read /etc/hosts -
>   1 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[1200]: read
>   /tmp/hosts/odhcpd - 1 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[1200]: read
>   /tmp/hosts/dhcp - 1 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]: read
>   /etc/ethers - 0 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[1200]: read /etc/hosts -
>   1 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[1200]: read
>   /tmp/hosts/odhcpd - 2 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[1200]: read
>   /tmp/hosts/dhcp - 1 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]: read
>   /etc/ethers - 0 addresses
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:23 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:23 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:25 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:25 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:29 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:29 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:37 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:48:37 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 REQUEST IA_NA
>   from 000100011f6c96676c2483027dc9 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::9ea/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:49:49 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1956.330000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:49:50 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1956.760000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:49:54 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1961.420000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:49:56 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1962.740000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:49:56 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1962.880000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:49:57 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1963.940000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:49:57 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1964.180000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:50:13 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 1980.460000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:04 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:04 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:04 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:04 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:07 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:07 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:07 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:07 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:52:18 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2104.810000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:54:05 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2212.330000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:54:08 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2215.260000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:54:08 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2215.600000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:54:09 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2215.950000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:54:13 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2220.220000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:54:15 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2222.060000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:54:15 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2222.100000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:56:34 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2360.810000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:58:21 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2468.330000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:58:24 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2471.090000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:58:24 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2471.350000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:58:25 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2472.430000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:58:25 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2472.650000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:58:29 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2476.660000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 14:58:30 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2476.800000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:00:50 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2616.810000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:18 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:18 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:18 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:18 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:21 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:37 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2724.330000] br-lan:
>   received  packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:37 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2724.440000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:43 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2730.220000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:43 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2730.400000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:44 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2731.660000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:45 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2731.780000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:02:46 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2733.420000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:05:06 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2872.810000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:06:53 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2980.330000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:06:54 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2980.900000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:06:56 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2983.670000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:06:57 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2983.730000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:06:58 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2984.770000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:06:59 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2986.360000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:07:01 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 2987.720000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:22 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:22 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3068.910000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:22 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3068.910000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:24 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:24 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:24 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:24 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:25 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:25 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:25 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:25 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:27 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:27 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:27 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:27 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.133 68:5d:43:bc:c8:89
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:28 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:28 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:28 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPINFORM(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:28 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:34 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:34 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:34 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3081.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:35 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:35 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:35 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3082.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:36 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:36 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:36 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:36 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1200]:
>   DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.204 5c:9a:d8:6a:00:d2
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:36 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3082.920000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:36 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3082.930000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:36 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3083.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:37 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:37 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:37 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3084.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:38 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3085.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:39 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3086.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:41 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:41 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:41 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3088.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:42 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3089.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:43 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3090.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:49 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:49 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:49 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3096.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:50 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3097.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:08:51 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3098.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:05 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:05 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3112.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:05 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:06 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3113.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:07 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3114.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:21 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3127.690000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:21 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3128.590000] br-lan:
>   received  packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:22 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3128.810000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:22 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3129.590000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:37 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:37 2016 daemon.warn odhcpd[778]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA
>   from 000100011f731a055c9ad86a00d2 on br-lan: ok
>   fdf0:72e6:a7ba::411/128
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:37 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3144.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:38 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3145.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Tue Dec  6 15:09:39 2016 kern.warn kernel: [ 3146.030000] br-lan:
>   received packet on eth0 with own address as source address